# javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Table not found

Tags: ignite

My code starts the node and executes the loadCache() method but when SQL query is applied to it, it gives the error mentioned in the title. Here is my code for configuration, cachestore and loadcache:

Configuration.java:

```
public class Configuration {

/** Helper class for datasource creation. **/
public static class DataSources {
    public static final JdbcDataSource dataSource = createdataSource();

    private static JdbcDataSource createdataSource() {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();

        dataSource.setURL("");
        dataSource.setUser("");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }
}

/**
 * Configure grid.
 * 
 * @return Ignite configuration.
 * @throws Exception If failed to construct Ignite configuration instance.
 **/
public static IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() throws Exception {
    //int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("Reports");

    TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

    ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList(""));

    discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);


    //cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheOutputReportCache());

    return cfg;
}



 //Configuration for cache "OutputReportCache".
public static CacheConfiguration<Long, OutputReport> cacheOutputReportCache() throws Exception {
    CacheConfiguration<Long, OutputReport> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();

    ccfg.setName("OutputReportCache");
    ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);

    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, OutputReport> cacheStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();

    cacheStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override 
        public DataSource create() {
            return DataSources.dataSource;
        };
    });

    cacheStoreFactory.setDialect(new OracleDialect());

    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);

    ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

    ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    qryEntity.setKeyType(String.class.getName());
    qryEntity.setValueType(OutputReport.class.getName());

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    fields.put("sid", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("sName", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("cname", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("cnumber", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("cname", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("cid", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("r", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("b", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Date", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Side", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Quant", "java.lang.Float");
    fields.put("price", "java.lang.Float");
    fields.put("local", "java.lang.Float");
    fields.put("usd", "java.lang.Float");
    fields.put("trcy", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Count", "java.lang.Integer");
    fields.put("Type", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Category", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Subcategory", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Country", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("eCountry", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Desc", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Sector", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("isector", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Flag", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("Region", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("rowNum", "java.lang.Long");

    qryEntity.setFields(fields);

 // Listing indexes.
    Collection<QueryIndex> indexes = new ArrayList<>(3);

    indexes.add(new QueryIndex("sid"));
    indexes.add(new QueryIndex("Region"));
    indexes.add(new QueryIndex("cnumber"));
    indexes.add(new QueryIndex("eCountry"));

    qryEntity.setIndexes(indexes);

    qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

    ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

    return ccfg;
}
}
```

OutputReportStore.java:

```
public class OutputReportStore implements CacheStore<Long, OutputReport> {
    //@SpringResource(resourceName = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource = DataSources.dataSource;
    // This method is called whenever IgniteCache.loadCache() method is called.
    @Override
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, OutputReport> clo, @Nullable Object... objects) throws CacheLoaderException {
        System.out.println(">> Loading cache from store...");
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from OUTPUTREPORT")) {
                try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        OutputReport outputreport = new OutputReport(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getFloat(11), rs.getFloat(12), rs.getFloat(13), rs.getFloat(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getInt(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26), rs.getLong(27));
                        clo.apply(outputreport.getrowNum(), outputreport);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CacheLoaderException("Failed to load values from cache store.", e);
        }
    }

    // Other CacheStore method implementations.
    @Override
    public OutputReport load(Long arg0) throws CacheLoaderException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(Object arg0) throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void write(Entry<? extends Long, ? extends OutputReport> arg0)
            throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public Map<Long, OutputReport> loadAll(Iterable<? extends Long> arg0)
            throws CacheLoaderException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Collection<?> arg0) throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void writeAll(
            Collection<Entry<? extends Long, ? extends OutputReport>> arg0)
            throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void sessionEnd(boolean arg0) throws CacheWriterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

LoadCaches.java:

```
public class LoadCaches {
    //Load caches from database.
    //1. Start cluster
    //2. Start this utility and wait while load complete

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(Configuration.createConfiguration())) {

            System.out.println(">>> Loading cache: OutputReportCache");
            IgniteCache<Long, OutputReport> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("OutputReportCache");
    cache.loadCache(null);

    System.out.println(">>> Cache loaded!");

    QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select count(*) from outputreport"));
    System.out.println(cursor.getAll());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

> [16:59:22] Ignite node started OK (id=90c9464d, instance name=Reports)
>   [16:59:22] Topology snapshot [ver=29, servers=1, clients=6, CPUs=12,
>   offheap=90.0GB, heap=36.0GB] [16:59:22]   ^-- Node
>   [id=90C9464D-A48A-4DB7-8812-65CE5FD4B8FD, clusterState=ACTIVE]
>
> > > > Loading cache: OutputReportCache
> > > >         Cache loaded! Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Table
> > > >         "OUTPUTREPORT" not found; SQL statement: select count(*) from
> > > >         outputreport [42102-196]  at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:676)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:615)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:356)
> > > >           at project4.LoadCaches.main(LoadCaches.java:26) Caused by: class
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed
> > > >         to parse query. Table "OUTPUTREPORT" not found; SQL statement: select
> > > >         count(*) from outputreport [42102-196]    at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatementAndCaches(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2026)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.parseAndSplit(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1796)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.querySqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1652)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2035)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2030)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2578)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2044)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:664)
> > > >           ... 3 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table
> > > >         "OUTPUTREPORT" not found; SQL statement: select count(*) from
> > > >         outputreport [42102-196]  at
> > > >         org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
> > > >           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
> > > >         org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5552)   at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1266)   at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1946)     at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2095)     at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1940)    at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1755)  at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1743)   at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:449)  at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321)  at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)  at
> > > >         org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258)     at
> > > >         org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)  at
> > > >         org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)    at
> > > >         org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepare0(IgniteH2Indexing.java:484)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:452)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:419)
> > > >           at
> > > >         org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatementAndCaches(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2008)
> > > >           ... 11 more

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Could you please update your question with a full stack trace and provide us with `OutputReport ` class definition?

Comment: Update your cache store configuration with JdbcTypes initialization according to https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/f575a245cf9958857e0f51d7f56db43f0d3a2d5c/modules/core/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPojoStoreTest.java and try again.

Comment: @sk0x50 The given stack trace is the complete one. And OutputReport class has the field names as included in Configuration.java and constructor along with getter and setter methods for each field.

Comment: I replaced cache() with getOrCreateCache() and the NullPointerException was resolved. But when I tried to query the cache, it says the table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the root cause of `NullPointerException` exception is that the `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory#types` is not defined in your code. It can be done via Java API as follows:

```
JdbcType storeType = new JdbcType;
storeType.setDatabaseSchema("Your-custom-schema");
storeType.setDatabaseTable("Table-name");
storeType.setKeyType(Long.class);
storeType.setValueType(OutputReport.class);
storeType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "sName", String.class, null));
...

cacheStoreFactory.setTypes(storeType);
```

You can find an example here: [CacheJdbcPojoStoreTest](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPojoStoreTest.java)

Comment: Well, this exception means that you need to properly specify the table name.
I think it should be something like the following: `select count(*) from OutputReport ` instead fo `outputreport`

Comment: SQL Queries are case-insensitive. Doesn't matter how I specify the table name. I still tried what you suggested. Got the same error again.

Comment: Is it possible to share your project on GitHub? In that case, I will try to check your code and debug the issue.

Comment: @PragyaMalik Can you provide a simple reproducer? This way it will be much easier to get help.